# Order Json object based on the values

Tags: javascript, json, object

Here down a snippet of my program:

```js
var items = {"43":"1255","44":"1243","45":"8080","46":"9898"};
var result = Object.keys(items).map(function(e) {
    return [items[e],Number(e)];
});
console.log(result);
```

I would need to order the `items` based on the values so to have an output *JSON* as below:

```js
{
    "44":"1243",
    "43":"1255",
    "45":"8080",
    "46":"9898"
};
```

Comment: Many thanks! @tmarwen

Comment: You are welcome @Mahendraprasath D